# How to remove Rails 3.2.16 after installed using apt-get?

Tags: rails, ruby-on-rails

How to remove Rails 3.2.16 after installed using apt-get?

I tried use "sudo apt-get purge rails" but it not working.

I typed "rails -v" then it return "3.2.16".

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: After removing close terminal and launch another and try, if that doesn't work restart system ans check...

Comment: Also check with: `which rails`...

Comment: I try restart my laptop but it didn't work.

Comment: which rails, it return /usr/local/bin/rails

Comment: Please can I see the command you used to install rails with...?

Comment: sudo apt-get install rails 3.2

Comment: try `sudo apt-get purge rails*`, just did it on my VM

Comment: Thanks you, It work well for me. You help me save much time. :D

Comment: Nice to hear all the best :)